# Gluing together mixed normed vector spaces with mixed topologies

Tags: ct.category-theory, banach-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

This is a variant of this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/350339/gluing-together-dense-subset-of-projective-limit-in-ban-1?noredirect=1#comment877746_350339).

**Definitions/Facts**

---

- $Ball_1(X)$ denotes the unit ball (about $0$) in a normed vector space $X$.
- **MixTop** of triples of pairs $(X,\tau)$ of normed vector spaces $X$ equipped with a LC (locally convex) topology $\tau$ on $X$ making $Ball_1(X)$ complete and bounded together with [short linear maps](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/350339/gluing-together-dense-subset-of-projective-limit-in-ban-1?noredirect=1#comment877746_350339) whose restriction to the unit ball is $\tau$-continuous.
- **MixTop** contains the category $Ban_1$ of Banach spaces and continuous short linear maps and similarly it is complete, see [this article](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1975-053-01/S0002-9939-1975-0383059-5/S0002-9939-1975-0383059-5.pdf).

**Question**

---

Let $(X_n,\pi_n^{m})$ be a countable projective system in **MixTop**,thus $\projlim X_n$ is  well-defined therein.  Suppose further that, a strict variant of the [Mittag-Leffer condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_limit#Mittag-Leffler_condition) holds true:
$$
\pi_m^n(Ball_1(X_n)) \subseteq \overline{\pi_k^n(Ball_1(X_k))} \qquad \forall k \geq n,
$$
and that $U\subseteq \projlim X_n$ such that:
$$
\overline{\pi_n(U)}=X_n,
$$
then  is $U$ dense in $\projlim X_n$ itself?

Comment: You will find a more comprehensive treatment inthe book „Saks spaces and applications to functional analysis“ by the same author. The appropriate assumptions for a theorem of this type would be a projective limit of Banach spaces so that the images of the unit balls are dense in the balls of the image space.

Comment: I'm reading the suggested monograph, however I can't find the said theorem.  Is is known?

Comment: Not to my knowledge.  I guess that it follows from the Bourbaki version, resp. its proof but I have no access at the moment. Best to work on a proof yourself.